# Should I remove upstart binary from my upgraded Ubuntu 16.04 server?

Tags: 16.04, upstart, systemd, mythtv

I recently updated my server from 14.04 to 16.04 LTS.

I had some issues, particularly with mysql and mythtv. Eventually I got it working, however .....

Whenever I do an update I get upstart error message:

> status: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused

when the updated application restarts. They are restarting, so systemd is doing its thing.

mythtv-setup is not working properly. It's not shutting down or restarting the backend as it should. Getting similar messages on the terminal.

The upstart binary is still on my system. I'm assuming that some startup scripts are also still there, hence the upstart errors when applications are starting.

Should I remove the upstart binary? Better still, purge it to remove any redundant scripts?

I'm nervous about doing this as the I don't want an unbootable box, although my gut feeling is it should be ok as systemd handles this now and seems to be working.

Thanks.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-meta/+bug/1582421 upstart is still used in 16.04 for user sessions. In 16.10, systemd is used for that, but upstart is still installed.

Answer (score 1):

No. If you run `sudo apt-get remove upstart`, you'll discover what depends on it, because these packages would get removed to.

You'll see this:

`The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libunity-2d-private0 ubuntu-desktop unity unity-2d unity-2d-common unity-2d-panel unity-2d-shell unity-2d-spread unity-greeter upstart`

Notably, both "ubuntu-desktop" and "unity" depend on Upstart being installed, so leave Upstart installed.

I would instead focus your energy on confirming that your MythTV install is compatible with configured correctly for Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: No, it doesn't. It only says it will remove unity-greeter (from memory). It further says there will be a bunch of redundant which can be removed with apt-get autoremove. As my box is a server, I dont really need all this desktop stuff.

Comment: Mythtv is working perfectly except for the setup program. Everything is being controlled by systemd. It seems that upstart is only called from scripts. My only concern is if I get rid of upstart the box won't boot, although I don't know why it wouldn't.

Comment: Found the problem in mythtv-setup. There's line that checks whether mythtv-backend is running, using an upstart status command which doesn't work anymore. Changing "status mythtv-backend" to "systemctl status mythtv-backend" makes the setup program work as before. The 'service start and stop' commands still work with systemd so don't need to be changed.